# SQL check time value between a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query which checks whether a variable is between a time range in separate columns in the database.. If it is, then I would like to return the row.

When I use the following I get the following result

```
   declare @mytime datetime = '20160917 07:56'
select *
from OEEEvent oe
inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEEConfigEvent ce on oe.lOEEConfigEventId = ce.lOEEConfigEventId
inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEELOVCodeVal rs on oe.sStartVal = rs.sDescription and ce.lOEEIntRSSqlId=rs.lOEELOVCodeId
inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEEStateConfig mms on rs.lMachineState = mms.lOEEStateConfigId

where tstart > @mytime
```

[image]

However, when I change the query to check whether the variable @mytime is between the time range, I get no result. The @mytime variable has been changed to 8am which we can previously see there was data there.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post **images!!**. Post the original code/result in text format it will be easy to copy paste and replicate the issue or to test

Comment: Do you want compare date including seconds ?

Comment: Hi prdp, I just want to check if the myDate variable is between the date range created by the tstart and tend column in the database

Comment: Ok, you current input is `2016-09-17 07:56:00.000` and consider `tstart` is `2016-09-17 07:56:45.000`  and `tEnd` is `2016-09-17 08:00:00.000`. Do you want to include this row ?

Comment: since tstart = 7.56 and tend = 8.21. When mytime = 8.00am, I would like to return this row only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using Variable in where condition as following:

```
WHERE @mytime BETWEEN  tstart  AND tend
```

And for addressing hour and minute only, it should work please try:

```
WHERE LEFT(@mytime, 17) BETWEEN LEFT(tstart, 17) AND LEFT(tend, 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to trim seconds from your `datetime` column

```
Select DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, yourcolumn), 0)
```

something like this should help you

```
declare @mytime datetime = '20160917 07:56'

Select ..
where @mytime between DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, tstart ), 0) and 
                                          DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, tEnd ), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition like below. In your case the second condition will not satisfy the data range (tend >@mytime)

```
       WHERE  tstart >@mytime and @mytime <tend
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to express BETWEEN, it's starttime < yourtime < endtime. It equals to

```
startTime < yourTime AND yourTime < endTime
```

while you write statement in opposite way

```
startTime > yourTime and yourTime > endTime
```

So change where clause to

```
tstart < @mytime AND @mytime < tend
```

You can use `BETWEEN` operator, but please notice `BETWEEN` operator include both range. See if it satisfy your requirement.